# Pronunciation of infinitives ending with "ere"

Tags: pronunciation

I've noticed that certain infinitives ending with "ere" are pronounced with emphasis on the second to last syllable, e.g. tacere, while others are pronounced with emphasis on the third to last syllable, e.g. prendere, premere, correre, etc.

Is there a general rule for determining the position of the accent for the "ere" infinitives?